# onclick window.open AND alert

Tags: javascript, html

Using JavaScript, I am putting some HTML code into a div, which `onclick` I want to run a file and also alert the user. The issue I am having is that it will run the program fine, but will not alert. Below is the code I have so far:

```
function novpn() {
    var output = document.getElementById("main");
    document.getElementById('main').scrollIntoView();
    var sentence ="<div id='continue' onclick='window.open(\"filepath"); alert('CLICK RUN');'></div>";

    output.innerHTML = sentence;
}
```

Comment: Check your escaping of quotes.

Comment: The SO syntax highlighter will show you the error. `window.open(\"filepath");` <-- Escape the last double quote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is just how you're escaping your `sentence` html.

```
function novpn() {
  var output = document.getElementById("main");
  document.getElementById('main').scrollIntoView();
  var sentence ="<div id='continue' onclick='window.open(\"filepath\"); alert(\"CLICK RUN\");'>CLICK ME</div>";
  output.innerHTML = sentence;
}
```

Should work. See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q4I0JNDXjLA094stYAkN?p=preview